# Gdal warp cutline overhang

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

I'm currently trying to cutline crop a tif with a shapefile and no matter what I do I have pixel either overhanging the cutline or being cropped too early.

So here is an example picture of what is happening when I use gdalwarp:
[image]

When I use arcpy to crop I get this result:

[image]

The code I am currently using with gdal warp is:

```
 gdalwarp.exe -ot "float32" -s_srs "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 
 +no_defs " -t_srs "+proj=utm
 +zone=48 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs "-of "GTiFF" -cutline 
 mask.shp -crop_to_cutline infile.asc outfile.tif -wm 5000 -tap -tr 100 100 -overwrite
```

I am quite keen to use gdal if possible to do this cropping as it is considerably faster

---

I have been asked to provide gdalinfo info, see below.
This is from the gdal code:
[image]

This is from the arcpy code: 
[image]

SOLUTION was found in comments.

Exactly what I wanted:

[image]

My new problem to ponder next is: 
[[image]]

Comment: What is the output from a gdalinfo on the arcpy result?

Comment: Have added two new pictures with gdal info for both datasets

Comment: And is the resolution of the input data also 100m?

Comment: The resolution of your arcpy image seems to be much higher along the cutline. Or is the cutline covering part of pixels? Are the visible blocks in the raster 100 by 100 meters in size?

Comment: Both arcpy and gdal are given the same data input, which has a pixel size of 1000x1000 but it then reprojected to be 100x100.

Comment: The exact resolution I am not sure exactly, but it is smaller than the pixel size

Comment: You could try setting -wo CUTLINE_ALL_TOUCHED=TRUE, so that all pixels overlapping the cutline polygon will be selected, not just those whose center point falls within the polygon. see http://www.gdal.org/structGDALWarpOptions.html#a0ed77f9917bb96c7a9aabd73d4d06e08

Comment: also I would not set -tr option, because it forces gdal to use 100 pixel size instead of calculating suitable pixel size to follow the cutline

Comment: I am very happy to announce that  -wo CUTLINE_ALL_TOUCHED=TRUE did exactly what I wanted! Now I just need to fix the problem that is projection co-ords are ever so slighty off. See picture in post edit for your curiosity.

Comment: Please consider writing the solution as an answer, and accepting it. This will mark the question as answered for future reference.

Comment: Hi, I will do tomorrow when I get back to work. I am gonna leave this tab open to remind me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solutiuon was to add the option:  -wo CUTLINE_ALL_TOUCHED=TRUE